# good references on Compact Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

Can someone suggest some good references on Compact Operators?

By background being a first course in Functional Analysis.

Comment: I find Pederson’s Analysis NOW useful. As well as Conway’s A Course in Functional Analysis.

Comment: Conway has a good discussion of Sturm Liouville problems, which applies the theory of compact operators to differential equations

Comment: It might help to give more details of what you're looking for.  But my nomination is John R. Ringrose, ["Compact Non-Self-Adjoint Operators"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=aAGrAAAAIAAJ).

Comment: For compact operators on Hilbert spaces I can recommend ["Introduction to Functional Analysis" (1997) by Meise & Vogt](https://books.google.de/books?id=FavCGyUirRkC&dq=meise+vogt+introduction+to+functional+analysis&hl=de&source=gbs_navlinks_s) *(Chapter 15 & 16)* as well as ["Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics. I: Functional Analysis" (1980) by Reed & Simon](https://books.google.de/books/about/Methods_of_Modern_Mathematical_Physics_F.html?id=fXX0j4qa8G8C&redir_esc=y) *(Section VI)*.